# Htaccess Redirect Rule Not Working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We have this rewrite rule in effect, but we are having issues with the blog "Next" page links not working. This an example URL that is not working: http://www.mydomain.com/blog/page/2/ it is being redirected to http://www.mydomain.com/page/2/ (which displays the site home page).

Here is the current rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /blog/$ [NC]   
RewriteRule (.*) %1 [L]   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^blog/$ [NC]   
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

We previously had our blog posts reside under the /blog/ folder, but the new site has now rendered the blog posts at the root level (http://www.mydomain.com/category/some-blog-post/). So this rule is redirecting the old indexed blog posts to the new URL structure.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC you want to redirect `www.mydomain.com/blog/<anything>` to `www.mydomain.com/<anything>`

If that's correct, then the only thing to to should be:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
```

**EDIT**

Ok, after the precisions in the comment:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ! ^/blog/page.*
RewriteRule ^blog/([^/]+)/(.*) /$1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Not exactly. We still have the "home page" of the blog reside at /blog/ and the pagination links are still at http://www.mydomain.com/blog/page/X/ . We are just redirecting the old individual blog posts from /blog/category/some-blog-post/ to /category/some-blog-post/